# using 'this' keyword in 'super()' constructor

Tags: java

I want to use `this` in `super` constructor, but there is no way to call `this` before calling `supertype` constructor. 
I have got 3 classes. I will describe my exact problem using an example.

```
public class A {
    C c;
    A(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    B(C c) {
        super(new C(this)); // error
    }
}

public class C {
    A a;
    C(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: You're using `A` for every constructor name, even in `B` and `C`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the `this` reference to something else before the instance has been constructed.  If this was allowed, the `C` constructor would be given an reference to a partial `B` object.  That would break abstraction for `B`.

The section of the JLS that talks about this is [8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1).  It says:

> An explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body may not refer to any instance variables or instance methods or inner classes declared in this class or any superclass, **or use this or super in any expression**; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

---

> I understand the problem, but I am asking, how to solve it. I need class C to have its "owner" from when it is created but I also need class A to "own" it from beginning.

You must pass the `B` reference to the `C` instance *after* constructing `B`; i.e. by assigning a new value to `C.b`, directly or via a method call such as a setter.   There is no way around this.  Java doesn't provide a way to create objects AND make them into a cycle in a constructor chain.

One way to hide the cycle creation is to use the [Builder Design Pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/).  But a setter call or equivalent has to happen behind the scenes.

Note that if your `a` and `c` fields are both declared as `final`, then there is no pure Java solution at all.  (You could use some "nasty" reflection to modify one of the `final` variables.  Or possibly some trickery with object deserialization.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a parameter-less constructor to construct the `C` instance, and then use a setter to set the instance variable.

```
public class A {
    C c;
    A(C c) {
        this.c = c;
        c.setA(this);
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    B(C c) {
        super(new C());
    }
}

public class C {
    A a;
    C() {
    }
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BeetMacol the C instance would have a reference to its owner A via the call to the setter method in A's constructor.

Comment: @BeetMacol I don't think there is.